# sql: where subquery not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql query and I want to filter the results where the alias imagefile is null, but I can't get it to work. it's kinda basic sql... sorry for that!

```
SELECT Categorie.CategorieID, Categorie.Highlight, CategorieTaal.CategorieNaam,
        (SELECT TOP (1) ImageFile
                FROM Artikel WHERE (CategorieID = Categorie.CategorieID) 
                     AND (Onzichtbaar = 0) 
                     AND (NietBestelbaar = 0) 
                     AND (Voorraad = - 1000 OR Voorraad > LevertijdDrempel)
                     ORDER BY Volgnummer, ArtikelID DESC) AS 'imagefile' 
        FROM Categorie INNER JOIN 
                     CategorieTaal ON 
                     Categorie.CategorieID = CategorieTaal.CategorieID  
        WHERE (Categorie.CategorieGroepID = @catgroepid) 
               AND (Categorie.Onzichtbaar = 0) 
               AND (CategorieTaal.TaalCode = @tc) 
       ORDER BY Categorie.Volgnummer, CategorieTaal.CategorieNaam
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```
SELECT Categorie.CategorieID, Categorie.Highlight, CategorieTaal.CategorieNaam,
FROM Categorie 
INNER JOIN 
    CategorieTaal ON
    Categorie.CategorieID = CategorieTaal.CategorieID  
WHERE (Categorie.CategorieGroepID = @catgroepid) 
    AND (Categorie.Onzichtbaar = 0) 
    AND (CategorieTaal.TaalCode = @tc) 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 ImageFile
        FROM Artikel WHERE (CategorieID = Categorie.CategorieID) 
            AND (Onzichtbaar = 0) 
            AND (NietBestelbaar = 0) 
            AND (Voorraad = - 1000 OR Voorraad > LevertijdDrempel))
ORDER BY Categorie.Volgnummer, CategorieTaal.CategorieNaam
```

Comment: one small thing: there is a ',' too much on the first line. and 'NOT' should be out the query to get the correct results.
execution time : 129 in sql management studio

Answer (score 1):

found it!!

```
SELECT  Categorie.CategorieID, Categorie.Highlight, CategorieTaal.CategorieNaam,
        (SELECT TOP (1) ImageFile
            FROM Artikel
            WHERE (CategorieID = Categorie.CategorieID)
                AND (Onzichtbaar = 0)
                AND (NietBestelbaar = 0)
                AND (Voorraad = - 1000
                    OR Voorraad > LevertijdDrempel)
            ORDER BY Volgnummer, ArtikelID DESC) AS 'imagefile'
FROM Categorie
INNER JOIN CategorieTaal ON Categorie.CategorieID = CategorieTaal.CategorieID
WHERE (Categorie.CategorieGroepID = @catgroepid)
    AND (Categorie.Onzichtbaar = 0)
    AND (CategorieTaal.TaalCode = @tc)
    AND ((
            SELECT TOP (1) ImageFile
                FROM Artikel AS Artikel_1
                WHERE (CategorieID = Categorie.CategorieID)
                    AND (Onzichtbaar = 0)
                    AND (NietBestelbaar = 0)
                    AND (Voorraad = - 1000
                        OR Voorraad > LevertijdDrempel)
    ) IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY Categorie.Volgnummer, CategorieTaal.CategorieNaam
```

Comment: execution time: 210 :S (worst possible option atm)

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize this by using an `inner join` again, in lieu of trying to use a subquery twice:

```
SELECT 
    c.CategorieID, 
    c.Highlight, 
    ct.CategorieNaam,
    a.ImageFile
FROM 
    Categorie c 
    INNER JOIN CategorieTaal ct ON 
        c.CategorieID = ct.CategorieID
    INNER JOIN 
        (select 
             CategorieID,
             ImageFile, 
             row_number() over (partition by CategorieID) as rownum
         from
             Artikel
         where
             Onzichtbaar = 0
             and NietBestelbaar = 0
             and (Voorraad = -1000 OR Voorraad > LevertijdDrempel)) a ON
        c.CategorieID = a.CategorieID
        and a.rownum = 1
WHERE 
    c.CategorieGroepID = @catgroepid
    AND c.Onzichtbaar = 0
    AND ct.TaalCode = @tc
ORDER BY c.Volgnummer, ct.CategorieNaam
```

Since you're using SQL Server (or at least I think you are, with your `top` and whatnot), you can take advantage of `row_number`. This will bring back just the `ImageFile` you need, *without* having to do two correlated subqueries (usually performance killers).

Also, here you only have to maintain that subquery in one place, not in two different parts of your query.

Comment: wow really impressive. i am not that good with sql.it's indeed sql server2005 but when i ran your query i got: The ranking function "row_number" must have an ORDER BY clause.
so i changed the line with row_number() to:
row_number() over (partition by CategorieID order by artikelid desc) as rownum
but when i included the 'client statistics' in the management studio it said that it's not faster then the one i posted with the subquery in the where clause. maybe i am looking at the wrong numbers in sql management studio 2008? how can i measure it for sure? thanks for your reply, i learned from it